# Lucene wildcard query with single digits returning no hits

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am constructing a lucene query in code in order to make a call to a third party API to retrieve records that match a postcode search.

I'm attempting to nullify spaces from the search, either from what is in the base data being searched on or what the user inputs, so that -

- if the user searched for 'BU7 8DD' then records that contained 'BU78DD' or 'BU 78 DD' would be returned
- if the user searched for 'U78D' then records that contained 'BU7 8DD' or 'BU 78 DD' would be returned

I thought I could do this by doing a wildcard search for each character of the text the user entered, in that my lucene query would look like this, however it is not returning any results -

```
user searches: "BU7 8DD"

(PONO:*B* AND PONO:*U* AND PONO:*7* AND PONO:*8* AND PONO:*D* AND PONO:*D*)

results: 0
```

From some investigation I beliveve it is the inclusion of the numbers that is the issue as when I do the query without the numbers I am getting results -

```
(PONO:*B* AND PONO:*U* AND PONO:*D* AND PONO:*D*)

results: 2
    BU7 8DD
    BD18 0UP
```

Whereas if I do a search with a wildcard number on the same dataset I get no results -

```
(PONO:*7*)

results: 0
```

As an aside, it seems to work with numbers if I do a wildcard search on more than one character -

```
(PONO:*U7*)

results: 1
   BU7 8DD
```

I've had a look around and some solutions suggest it might be the way the data is indexed and custom parsers but I don't have access to the way the data is indexed and can only search through the query.

Would anyone know if there is something special I have to do for wildcard searches for single numbers? or is there a better way to do a search ignoring spaces?